# Applying Central Limit Theorem to an exponential distribution - how big should sample size be?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, sampling-theory

For an exponential distribution, in order for the sampling distribution of its mean to be well approximated by normal distribution (via central limit theorem), how big should a "typical" sample size be? In standard textbooks, sample size of $n = 30$ is often given; is this enough for a strongly skewed exponential distribution?

Comment: It really depends on how you are defining "good enough." If you need the distributions to be close, [Berry-Esseen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) gives you control over the the closeness of the CDFs.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the densities for the distributions (sample mean from exponential distribution - i.e. a gamma distribution - in black, normal distribution with same mean as the original exponential distribution  and standard deviation $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ times that in red)

for $n=10$:

[image]

and for $n=30$:

[image]

and for $n=90$:

[image]

It is for you to judge what amounts to "well approximated".

The skewness of $\frac{6}n$ diminishes towards $0$ as $n$ increases, so these charts have skewness $\frac13$ of the previous chart.